# Hibernate: Merging existing Entities with new "Double Parented" Children

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm having some difficulties to put a specific scenario to work with Hibernate...

Considering the snippet above (simplified model), Entities A and D already exist. They will receive new Children B and E, and E has also new C Childrens. Then I call the "merge" method in Entity Manager.

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.Lazy, cascade = CascadeType.All)
    private List<B> bList;

}

@Entity
public class B {

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinCollumn(name="ID_A")
    private A a;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b", fetch = FetchType.Lazy, cascade = CascadeType.All)
    private List<E> eList;

}

@Entity
public class C {

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinCollumn(name="ID_E")
    private E e;

}

@Entity
public class D {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "d", fetch = FetchType.Lazy, cascade = CascadeType.All)
    private List<E> bList;

}

// The "Double Parented" Children
@Entity
public class E {

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinCollumn(name="ID_B")
    private B b;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinCollumn(name="ID_D")
    private D d;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "e", fetch = FetchType.Lazy, cascade = CascadeType.All)
    private List<C> cList;

}

public class Example {
    public void newChildren() {
        A a = getExistingAfromDatabase(); // defined elsewhere
        E e = new E(); // then fills some attributes...
        B b = new B(); // then fills some attributes...

        b.getEs().add(e);
        e.setB(b);

        a.getBs().add(b);
        b.setA(a);

        edit(a);           
    }

    public void edit(A myEntity) {
        EntityTransaction trans = null;
        EntityManager eMngr = getEntityManager(); // this is defined in another place

        try {
            trans = eMngr.getTransaction();
            trans.begin();

            eMngr.merge(myEntity);
            trans.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (trans != null && trans.isActive())
                trans.rollback();

            throw new DAOException("Error! " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }       
    }
}
```

Whichever Entity I choose to merge first (A or D), I got the same exception: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: E.b -> B

Is Hibernate able to handle this with Cascade? If so, what have I done wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of how you are actually adding the new children and merging? The model's not really enough; the fix may have to do with how you are specifically using Hibernate.

Comment: @dcsohl is the code more helpful now? Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Hmmm. My only suggestions would be a) Try using `Set` instead of `List`, and b) make sure you're not mixing Hibernate and JPA annotations. Hibernate does support JPA and its annotations, but my understanding is, if you mix them up, things don't always work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you always set both the Parent and the Child, so taking A and B you should have this kind of utility method in your base class (e.g. A):

```
public void addChild(B child) {
    child.setA(this);
    this.bList.add(child);
}
```

This utilities should prevent you from getting this type of exceptions.

Comment: I've done this before, that doesn't solve my question.